# sorting out files to different directories from a main directory

Tags: command-line, unix, find

I have numerous files I am trying to move from a main directory in to separate directories which have multiple sub-directories inside.

Example file naming conventions 1SA_1BA_1W.out, 2SA_3BA_3W.out, 4SA_2BA_5W.out....

Is there a way given the number in from of each SA, BA, W or other items I have to move all at one time to a given location. The ranges of SA would be 1-10, BA 1-4 etc...

Currently I am using a script command such as........

```
find . -type f -name '1A_1HNO3_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_BA_W
find . -type f -name '2SA_*BA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_BA_W
find . -type f -name '3SA_*BA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_BA_W
find . -type f -name '4SA_*BA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_BA_W
find . -type f -name '1SA_*DEA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_DEA_W
find . -type f -name '2SA_*DEA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_DEA_W
find . -type f -name '3SA_*DEA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_DEA_W
find . -type f -name '4SA_*DEA_*W.out' | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /location/SA_DEA_W
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. How about grouping `\( ... \)` and or-ing (`-o`) the `-name` predicates ? Also, you could definitely catch `{1..4}SA_*DEA*W.out` (that's Bash syntax, though) by using `?` as placeholder for a single character in the `-name` predicate.

Comment: Could you pls. explain in more detail based on what you want to move/copy which file to which location. Also, is the 1A_1HN... just a typo or why is moved/copied to /SA_BA_W?

Comment: for the 1A_1HNO3 line the SA_BA_W  directory was a typo it was suppose to go to the A_HNO3 directory. I have over 1700 files with various identification abbreviations, such as SA BA A HNO3 W MA EAM TMA DMA  DEA ect... I need to be able to get pull these files and transfer them into an easy database structure. The "location" would be the name of the main parent directory and folders like SA_DEA_W are sub directories inside the parent directory.